# How to define min/max zoom levels for which SKMapCustomPOI's are displayed?

Tags: android, skmaps

I am new to Skobbler and would like to add POIs to my map. However, I do not want them appearing at every zoom level, but rather at a specific margin of levels. I've seen that this is possible for Annotations via the setMininumZoomLevel method and was wondering if there is anything similar to this for the customPOI's. TIA

Answer (score 2):

A custom POI should be an annotation.

The POIs that you see on the map are OSM POIs - if you want to modify the visibility of those POIs, you will need to change the map style.

See this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572108/how-does-skobbler-prioritize-which-pois-to-show) for more context.

Comment: Thanks Ando, I've read the other thread but I seem to be missing something - In my specific case, I wish to add an SKPOI_CATEGORY_GUEST_HOUSE POI, and in the daystyle.json file it seems to be defined starting from zoom level 17. However, in runtime the POI is rendered at the same zoom level as the scale view (I beleive it's 3).

Comment: Please attach or provide a link to your style file so that we can take a look and see what is going on